# Why I'm getting empty object when doing post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I tried to do post request to other localhost server(because in project I'm using webpack and I don't know how to manage default webpack server).

This is my post request file.

```js
    btn_bag[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault(),
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/get', {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(order_pizza)
    })
      .then(console.log(order_pizza))
    })
```

This is my server, when I click on button, console in server logged {}, when "order_pizza"(variable which I post) is not empty. What is the problem, help to find solution, please.

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('hello')
    })
    app.use(cors({
        allowedOrigins: [
            'http://localhost:9000'
        ]
    }));
    app.get('/get', (req,res) => {
        console.log(req.body)
        res.send('get')})

    app.post('/get',urlencodedParser, (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)})

    app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your front-end, do not stringify the body, send it as an object like below.
Change also the targetted end-point to `/post`

```
  btn_bag[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(),
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/post', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: {order_pizza}
})
  .then(console.log(order_pizza))
})
```

In your server, change the end-point URL to `/post` so that it makes sense.
And access the request body like below.
And you do not need the `urlencodedParser` on this end-point

```
  app.post('/post', (req,res) => {
   console.log(req.body)})
  })
```

Also apply the body-parser to your express app like below

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

you don't have to pass urlencodedParser in app.post api call, i hope it helps